# Windows 10 open with context menu does not show network applications

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

When right clicking a file in Explorer in my Windows 10, the sub menu of the context menu entry *Open with* is empty. I only have the option *Choose another app*

When i click on the *Home* tab in explorer and I click on the *open* dropdown, I correctly get the list of associated applications for a file type.

So my question is: How can I fix the right click context menu to show the list of associated applications?

After some googling I already tried this registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Open With]
 @="{09799AFB-AD67-11d1-ABCD-00C04FC30936}"
```

But that didn't fix the problem and seems to be only to restore the *Open with* entry if it is completely missing.

Update: It seems the context menu only shows programs from my local hard drives, and does not list programs that are on a network share. So how do I get the applications from my network share listed. (I use a drive mapping for the network share)

Comment: Once you choose an application via Open with, it should get added to the open-with listing (or sub-menu).. as the OpenWithList or OpenWithProgId values are populated when you choose an application. The "Open with" option you see in the ribbon works differently.

Comment: Interesting: When I choose open with from the context menu and I choose Notepad++, the application is added to the list. But when I used a MFC or command line program, it is not added to the list whilst the ribbon list gets the entry.

Answer (score 0):

If by context menu you mean [This Context Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwuxr.png)
then you need to do a few simple things, as well as be an administrator. This worked for me but may not work for you, but I hope it does.

[image]

The first thing you want to do is head to [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and download the ShellExView.
After that you should run the program, and sort by Microsoft and Non-Microsoft. It should look like this.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Then select the grey ones that you need, right-click and "Enable Selected Items".

Comment: Using ShellExView, I see 'Open With Context Menu Handler' as enabled. I also have the menu entry, but the list is empty.