# windows 10 open with context menu empty

Tags: windows-10, context-menu, file-association

[image]

The Open with context menu doesn't show any options sometimes(Not even choose another app option) and sometimes it does. I suspect it shows blank when an application has been made default for that particular file type through the control panel set default option and shows the menu when no default is set, although I am not sure of this. Clicking on "Open with" does nothing. How do I fix this problem, [I found another post on Superuser with a sort of similar situation](https://superuser.com/questions/1041465/windows-10-open-with-context-menu-does-not-show-network-applications) but I don't want to mess with the registry unless I need to. I have found that this issue is specific to Windows Explorer, it works in other explorer software such as Q-Dir.

Comment: You need to at least try the suggest registry file.  Your only other solution would be to use the Refresh Windows 10 feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

1. Click Start, All Programs, Accesories, Notepad.
2. Copy and paste this text:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Open With]
   @="{09799AFB-AD67-11d1-ABCD-00C04FC30936}
   ```
3. Click File, Save As, name the file "**OpenWith.reg**" (WITH THE QUOTATION MARKS) and click OK.
4. Now double-click OpenWith.reg, click Continue, Yes, OK, and see if the problem is solved.

As a safety measure just create a system restore point since you are scared of messing up registry, it may be risky but also highly rewarding. Justtry it and see if it works.

Credits: [Right click 'Open With' Command missing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/right-click-open-with-command-missing-help-please/a9c3f139-075c-4285-b87d-25e899fb8b27)